# Issues on File Validation using python magic

Tags: python, django

I have made **validators.py** in Dimensions project directory for file validation (In Simple words, If It's a video model accept only mp4 ,If it's a image model accept jpg and png only).
But I dont't get it It gives me Validation error 'Sorry, Cannot accept unacceptable file extension' when I add for Video, Image, File to check. What am  I doing wrong? I couldn't figure out.

```
import os
import magic
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_is_video(file):
    valid_mime_types = ['application/.mov']
    file_mime_type = magic.from_buffer(file.read(1024), mime=True)
    if file_mime_type not in valid_mime_types:
        raise ValidationError('Sorry,Cannot accept unsupported file type.')
    valid_file_extensions = ['.mov',]
    ext = os.path.splitext(file.name)[1]
    if ext.lower() not in valid_file_extensions:
        raise ValidationError('Sorry,Cannot accept unacceptable file extension.')
    
def validate_is_image(file):
    valid_mime_types = ['application/.png','application/.jpg']
    file_mime_type = magic.from_buffer(file.read(1024), mime=True)
    if file_mime_type not in valid_mime_types:
        raise ValidationError('Sorry,Cannot accept unsupported file type.')
    valid_file_extensions = ['.png','.jpg']
    ext = os.path.splitext(file.name)[1]
    if ext.lower() not in valid_file_extensions:
        raise ValidationError('Sorry,Cannot accept unacceptable file extension.')    
    
def validate_is_audio(file):
    valid_mime_types = ['application/.mp3','application/.wav']
    file_mime_type = magic.from_buffer(file.read(1024), mime=True)
    if file_mime_type not in valid_mime_types:
        raise ValidationError('Sorry,Cannot accept unsupported file type.')
    valid_file_extensions = ['.mp3','.wav']
    ext = os.path.splitext(file.name)[1]
    if ext.lower() not in valid_file_extensions:
        raise ValidationError('Sorry,Cannot accept unacceptable file extension.')        
    
def validate_is_file(file):
    valid_mime_types = ['application/.zip','application/.rar']
    file_mime_type = magic.from_buffer(file.read(1024), mime=True)
    if file_mime_type not in valid_mime_types:
        raise ValidationError('Sorry,Cannot accept unsupported file type.')
    valid_file_extensions = ['.zip','.rar']
    ext = os.path.splitext(file.name)[1]
    if ext.lower() not in valid_file_extensions:
        raise ValidationError('Sorry,Cannot accept unacceptable file extension.')
```

In **models.py** of an Player app

```
from django.db import models
from Dimensions.validators import *
# Create your models here.

class  Image(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    product = models.FileField(upload_to="Image/%y",validators=(validate_is_image,),null=True,blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)    

class  Video(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    product = models.FileField(upload_to="Video/%y",validators=(validate_is_video,),null=True,blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)           
    
class Fileupload(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    product = models.FileField(upload_to="File/%y",validators=(validate_is_file,),null=True,blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Comment: Which Model/field is giving the error? Wha's the name and type of file you were uploading? Were you uploading via the admin or your own view?

Comment: all models are giving the error. None of these models works. product field is not working. Yes, I was uploading through admin, the product field doesn't accept any file extension. I don't know why?

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting the file type error? None of your `valid_mime_types` look like valid mime types

Comment: Thanks I solved it. Would you mind if  i ask you a question?  file_mime_type = magic.from_buffer(file.read(1024), mime=True).In this code what does 1024 refers to? I guess it's a file size?Am i wrong?

Comment: `file.read(1024)` reads and returns (up to) 1024 bytes of data from the file

Comment: Ok Got it but the above code is just for validation of file.I wonder if I could  write the code to chose only the images(with chose file button on Django admin page) from my local computer depending on the model that I have defined.

Comment: @Sam  can u post the solution...this looks like a v helpful code.